# Regular expression to match lines that contain a sub string but should not be followed by specific sub string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

In my case, I have multiple urls and I required to match some urls that  contains neither `abc` nor `xyz` .For example the given urls are as follows-
 - secure/api/abc/sometext
 - secure/api/xyz/sometext
 - secure/api/required/sometext
 - unsecure/api/sometext/sometext

Expected Result

- secure/api/required/sometext

Urls must be start with `secure/api/`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think this can solve your problem**

```
^secure\/api\/(?!.*(abc|xyz|\/{2,})).+\/sometext$
```

> Explanation

`^secure` - It matches word secure at the start of string.

`\/` - It matches literal character `/`.

`(?!.*(abc|xyz|\/{2,})).+` - Here `?!` indicate negative lookahead which.

```
  -This complete sentence means match any thing except word abc and xyz and '//'.
```

`$` - This indicate end of string.

**Here's one more version i think which will perform better**

```
^secure\/api\/(?:(?!.*(abc|xyz|\/{2,})).+)\/sometext$
```

> Details -

`?:` will make a non capturing group which will help improving performance

[image]

**P.S** - ***Here before posting any question i think you should read the code of conduct and do some homework or show some valid example about the specified input and desired output along with edge cases.***

Comment: With your regex it matches `secure/api/aaa/xyz/sometext` which is incorrect as per post.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Yeah thanks for letting me know the miss since question is not clear so i haven't considered edge case.This can be achieved very easily with just a little change

Comment: Well, the post clearly mentions this. See this **required to match some urls that contains neither abc nor xyz** from post. It says input should not be accepted if it contains either **abc** or **xyz**